How do I turn the first word in a cell into a hyperlink using a macro in LibreOffice Calc
I have a large spreadsheet and want to automate the process of converting the first word of each cell into a hyperlink, but keeping the rest of the text as it is. I.e. linktext appendedtext to be converted to [linktext] appendedtext (linktext appearing as a link). I can create the hyperlink, but cannot see how now to add the appended text. All my efforts seem to delete the hyperlink. Thank you for any help or suggestions. My code is:-
sub HyperLink

rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
rem define variables
dim document   as object
dim dispatcher as object
dim linktext as String
dim appendedtext as String
dim pos
dim contents as String

rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
rem get access to the document
document   = ThisComponent.CurrentController.Frame
dispatcher = createUnoService("com.sun.star.frame.DispatchHelper")
ThisCell = ThisComponent.CurrentSelection

rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
rem get data from selected cell
contents = ThisCell.String
pos = Instr(contents," ") 'get position of space character

rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------

    ThisCell.clearContents(4)
    linktext = Mid(contents, 1, pos-1)
    appendedtext = Mid(contents, pos)
    dim args1(0) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
    args1(0).Name = "ToPoint"
    args1(0).Value = ThisComponent.CurrentSelection.AbsoluteName
    
    dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:GoToCell", "", 0, args1())
    
    rem ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    dim args2(5) as new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue
    args2(0).Name = "Hyperlink.Text"
    args2(0).Value = linktext '"link"
    args2(1).Name = "Hyperlink.URL"
    args2(1).Value = "https://www.someurl.php?link=" & linktext
    args2(2).Name = "Hyperlink.Target"
    args2(2).Value = ""
    args2(3).Name = "Hyperlink.Name"
    args2(3).Value = ""
    args2(4).Name = "Hyperlink.Type"
    args2(4).Value = 1
    args2(5).Name = "Hyperlink.ReplacementText"
    args2(5).Value = ""
    
    dispatcher.executeDispatch(document, ".uno:SetHyperlink", "", 0, args2())
    
    'Don't know how to now append text without deleting the hyperlink

end sub

I have tried getting the cell contents as Value and String etc. but nothing seems to work.

Did you (manually) make sure that a cell can actually hold a hyperlink AND an appended text? I would do this before trying to automate it.

Yes. Cells can hold both a hyperlink and appended text. I started going through my spreadsheet doing this manually, but gave up when I realised that doing this for over three thousand cells was going to take a long time. Writig a macro seemed the obvious choice, but I am beginning to regret it now, and will probably end up doing it manually if I can't figure out how to get a macro to work!

Thanks for clarification (you might want to consider to add this to your question for the next visitors). -- If you have cells the way you want, have you tried to read them via a macro to see how they are represented?

This answer is modified from Lupp's answer in Ask LibreOffice community site, which was based on Andew Pitonyak's “Useful Macro Information”, subchapter 5.18.5. Apparently, the URL and separate text are stored as enumerated fields inside a cell.
The code should work whether you have 0, 1, 2, or more words inside a cell.
If there are 0 words, the Sub would simply exit. If there is 1 word, it would add an extra space at the end. If it's critical you don't have this, you can add more code to prevent this. 2nd word and beyond would simply be inserted back behind the URL word.
Sub InsertURLIntoCell
  Dim oText   'Text object for the current object
  Dim oField  'Field to insert
  Dim oCell   'Get a specific cell
  Dim aTexts()  ' Array of texts in the field
  Dim iUBound as Integer
  
  oCell = ThisComponent.CurrentSelection

  REM Create a URL Text field
  oField = ThisComponent.createInstance("com.sun.star.text.TextField.URL")

  REM This is the actual text that is displayed for the URL
  
  aTexts = Split(oCell.getString(), " ", 2)
  iUBound = UBound(aTexts)
  If (iUBound = -1) Then
    ' There are no strings in the field... just quit
    Exit Sub
  ElseIf (iUBound = 0) Then
    ' There is only 1 string, set 2nd string to blank
    ReDim Preserve aTexts(1)
    aTexts(1) = ""
  End If
     
  oField.Representation = aTexts(0)
  
  REM The URL property is just a text string of the URL itself.
  'oField.URL = ConvertToURL(oCell.getString())
  oField.URL = ConvertToURL("https://www.someurl.php?link=" & aTexts(0))
  
  REM The text field is added as text content into the cell.
  REM If you do not now set the string to zero, then the existing
  REM text will remain and the new URL text field will be appended
  REM to the end.
  oCell.setString("")
  oText = oCell.getText()
  oText.insertTextContent(oText.createTextCursor(), oField, False)
  oText.insertString(oText.getEnd(), " " & aTexts(1), False)  
End Sub

